# How to pass environment variables from YAML file OR git repo to docker container?

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, docker, yaml

is it possible to pass environment variables from a YAML file OR git repo to docker container?
I have a YAML file which contains my environment VARs that i want to use inside the docker container in a python script. How can i do this?

Many thanks!

Comment: `docker run --env-file`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can pass environment variables from your shell straight through to a service container just like with:
"docker run -e variable"

You can pass multiple environment variables from a file to a service container  just like with:
"docker run --env-file"

Comment: Thank you @Sandeep - so it means it is not possible to directly pass a YAML fiel to docker - because the --env-file has a different structure (key:value per line) - correct? I would have to prepare an environment file - right?`

Comment: Yeah, You need to prepare environment variable. It may work for you, or do you need any further clarification, let me know.